# Forward Reciprocity Failure With Reversing A Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am working on a function called Reverse() were I use only two Links to reverse the order of the elements in a Lists. I have searched many ways to do this but it always ends with a "Segmentation Fault." I have a method helps specify what's going wrong, but the most it can tell me is that when I create a List of five elements (not including the head and tail) that there is a "forward reciprocity failure at position 0." Please keep in mind that I do not want code given to me, but merely your opinion on what is going wrong.

```
void List<T>::Reverse ()                                                       
{                                                                              
  //make sure that the list is long enough                                     
  if( this->Empty())                                                           
    return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

  Link * link = this->head_;                                                   
  Link * temp = NULL;                                                          

  while( link != NULL )                                                        
  {                                                                              
    temp = link->next_;                                                        
    link->next_ = link->prev_;                                                 
    link->prev_ = temp;                                                        

    if( link->prev_ == NULL )                                                  
      head_ = link;                                                            

    link = link->prev_;                                                        
  }                                                                                 
  CheckLinks();                                                                
 }
```

Comment: Your while-loop will never get to run. So either `Empty ()` or `CheckLinks ()` is causing the problem. I'm guessing `CheckLinks ()` is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you that did help when I removed the Empty code. I added a Display( os, char) after the final loop but it seems that it reverses the reversing of the list.

Comment: The list is never reversed in the first place. You set `Link * temp = NULL`. Then the condition for your while-loop is `temp != NULL`. Because temp is NULL, the while-loop will never run and your list will not reverse. You probably meant `while (link != NULL)`.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed it but it still causes an error. Because it refers to position 0 I guess that something screwy is going on with head_.

Comment: The algorithm seems fine. What is your test input? The problem is likely somewhere else in your code. Do you initialize prev_ and next_ members to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm works fine. The bug is somewhere else in your code.

I created my own (very quick and dirty) Doubly-Linked List just to test this.
I did this all in one file.

My Link struct is slightly different from yours:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Link
{
    Link (const T &data, Link <T> *prev = NULL, Link <T> *next = NULL) ;

    T data ;
    Link <T> *next_ ;
    Link <T> *prev_ ;
};

template <typename T>
Link <T>::Link (const T &data, Link <T> *prev, Link <T> *next) : data (data), prev_ (prev), next_ (next)
{
}
```

Then here's my test List struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct List
{
    List () ;

    bool IsEmpty () const ;
    void Reverse () ;
    void CheckLinks () const ;

    Link <T> *head_ ;
};

template <typename T>
List <T>::List () : head_ (NULL)
{
}

template <typename T>
bool List <T>::IsEmpty () const
{
    return head_ == NULL ;
}

template <typename T>
void List <T>::Reverse ()
{
    if (this->IsEmpty () == true) {
        return ;
    }

    Link <T> *link = head_ ;
    Link <T> *temp = NULL ;

    while (link != NULL) {
        temp = link->next_ ;
        link->next_ = link->prev_ ;
        link->prev_ = temp ;

        if (link->prev_ == NULL) {
            head_ = link ;
        }

        link = link->prev_ ;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void List <T>::CheckLinks () const
{
    Link <T> *link = head_ ;

    while (link != NULL) {
        std::cout << link->data << " " ;
        link = link->next_ ;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

These are the tests I ran to make sure it was correct.

```
// Null List
void Test0 ()
{
    List <int> list ;

    list.CheckLinks () ;
    list.Reverse () ;
    list.CheckLinks () ;
}

// List with 1 node
void Test1 ()
{
    Link <int> n1 (1) ;

    List <int> list ;
    list.head_ = &n1 ;

    list.CheckLinks () ;
    list.Reverse () ;
    list.CheckLinks () ;
}

// List with 2 nodes
void Test2 ()
{
    Link <int> n1 (1) ;
    Link <int> n2 (2) ;

    n1.next_ = &n2 ;
    n2.prev_ = &n1 ;

    List <int> list ;
    list.head_ = &n1 ;

    list.CheckLinks () ;
    list.Reverse () ;
    list.CheckLinks () ;
}

// List with 3 nodes
void Test3 ()
{
    Link <int> n1 (1) ;
    Link <int> n2 (2) ;
    Link <int> n3 (3) ;

    n1.next_ = &n2 ;

    n2.prev_ = &n1 ;
    n2.next_ = &n3 ;

    n3.prev_ = &n2 ;

    List <int> list ;
    list.head_ = &n1 ;

    list.CheckLinks () ;
    list.Reverse () ;
    list.CheckLinks () ;
}

// List with 4 nodes
void Test4 ()
{
    Link <int> n1 (1) ;
    Link <int> n2 (2) ;
    Link <int> n3 (3) ;
    Link <int> n4 (4) ;

    n1.next_ = &n2 ;

    n2.prev_ = &n1 ;
    n2.next_ = &n3 ;

    n3.prev_ = &n2 ;
    n3.next_ = &n4 ;

    n4.prev_ = &n3 ;

    List <int> list ;
    list.head_ = &n1 ;

    list.CheckLinks () ;
    list.Reverse () ;
    list.CheckLinks () ;
}
```

And here's my main:

```
int main (void) 
{
    Test0 () ;
    Test1 () ;
    Test2 () ;
    Test3 () ;
    Test4 () ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Hopefully this adequately convinces you that your bug is elsewhere.